# Nuxt.js page transitions, @leave never executing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, transition, nuxt.js, gsap

I'm trying to have page transitions using with nuxt and Greensock (gsap), I can't seem to get it working. I don't want to animate page transitions using css only, because I want to easily chain animations on different elements.

Previously, with Vue I could simply use:

```
<transition @enter="enter" @leave="leave" appear mode="out-in">
  <router-view />
</transition>

export default {
  methods: {
    enter(el, done) {
      console.log('enter');
      // ... gsap animation code
    },
    leave(el, done) {
      console.log('leave');
      // ... gsap animation code
    }
  }
}
```

Now, with Nuxt, I can't seem to get it working. I use the exact same code in **layouts/default.vue**. Except I replace `<router-view/>` with `<nuxt/>`.

The "enter", "beforeEnter" methods works fine. It gets called on the initial page load, as well as anytime I change pages. **However, the "leave" method never gets called.**

What am I not understanding? I just need one place to manage all of my page transitions with javascript. I've been googling for a while now, looking through lots of examples, I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Spent a while trying to solve the same problem, and as far as I can tell you can't use the `<transition>` component to specify JS hook callbacks around a `<nuxt/>` component, presumably due to Nuxt handling routing differently.

You need to define the [`transition` property](https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-transition/#object) on each page, where `enter()` and `leave()` are *specific to that particular page*. For example, if you are on the Home page and navigate to the About page, Home's `leave()`and About's `enter()` will both trigger.

You can use a [mixin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html) to simplify adding different transitions to different pages:

**~/mixins/transitions.js**

```
export const typeA = {
  transition: {
    ...
  }
}

export const typeB = {
  transition: {
    ...
  }
}
```

**Component**

```
import { typeA } from '~/mixins/transitions'

export default {
  mixins: [
    typeA
  ]
}
```

You can also define a [default transition](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-transition) in `nuxt.config.js`, but you will only have access to the page element, which might not be suitable for more complex transitions.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I followed @mstslv and used transition property on page components, it's the best solution so far to get proper results. You can programmatically do transitions by checking `this.$route.path` for instance.

If you want to avoid redundancy, you can use the following code

```
import transition from "~/plugins/transitions"

export default {
..
transition,
..
}
```